# On Farkas's Lemma and Existence of a particular solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

This is a real life problem. I have a matrix $A$ which is $m\times n$. I want to check for the conditions on the existence a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A x \geq 0$.

The Farkas's Lemma, as I have it, reads like this:

> If $A$ is $m\times n$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ then only one of this conditions holds:
>
> > (1) $\exists$ $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A x \leq b$.
> >
> > (2) $\exists$ $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $y\geq0$, $yA = 0$ and $yb<0$.

I have been trying to use the Farkas Lemma. However, I don't see how can I use the lemma as I have $b=0$. If $b=0$ then no such $y$ exists  such that $yb<0$. Is there an ammendment to the FL that I can use for existence?

**Update:** I think I have come to a solution, but I would be thrilled to know someone else's opinion. So remember, matrix $A$ is $m\times n$ and I am looking to be able to guarantee that there is an $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A x \geq 0$. I will define $B=-A$ and $b=(-1,\dots,-1)'\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Now, apply Farkas's Lemma on matrix $B$ and vector $b$. Now (2) is fairly possible. And what happens if (2) is never true? Then (1) must be true, so that $\exists$ $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $B x \leq b$, and then $-A x \leq b <0$ so we have that $Ax>0$.

So all I have to do to prove existence is to deny (2). Now that is a very difficult problem, but it is a complete different subject.

Comment: In what sense are you attributing $<$ for vectors?

Comment: You mean on (2)? Well $yb$ is a scalar (dot product). I am right?

Comment: @CameronWilliams In this context it means component by component of the coordinate vector.

Comment: I normally see Farkas's lemma stated as, exactly one of the following alternatives is true: (1) There exists a vector $x$ such that $Ax \geq 0$ and $b^T x < 0$, or (2) There exists a vector $\mu \geq 0$ such that $b = A^T \mu$.

Comment: To my understanding, both statements are equivalent.

Comment: why do you need $b=(-1,\ldots,-1)$? Cant you use your Farkas directly? Since $yb<0$ cannot occur, we must have (1), so there exists $x'$ such that $Ax'\leq0$. Then for $x:=-x'$ we have $Ax\geq0$. Do I miss something?